# How can I see all the aplications and to select which one should be in start up?

Tags: startup

I would like to include in start up applications some additional programs, but I don’t know the launching command. Is it any simple way to see all the installed programs and to select the ones to be included in start up?

Answer (score 1):

in Startup applications, you go to "Add", and then "Browse". Most or all of your apps will be in the directory "/usr/bin". To get to that folder, after clicking "browse", on the left pane of the file explorer, clck "computer", then "usr", then "bin", then click the program you want to be on startup